# WSL: Ways to deal with bash script that was checked out on Windows

Tags: bash, git, windows-subsystem-for-linux, line-endings

I don't know if I' missing something here, but this is my current situation:

- GIT Repo checked out on Windows machine
- Line endings are automatically converted (autocrlf = true)
- installed WSL with Ubuntu

There are some Bash scripts in this repo that I want to execute via WSL. It doesn't work out-of-the-box due to the auto-converted line endings. So my current solution is to convert the script before execution with dos2unix.

Is there a fancy solution out there to get it working without manually converting the files?

Comment: Do you know ` .gitattributes`: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings

Comment: @MarkusMeyer as mentioned, the Repo is checked out on Windows, and GIT is configured to convert line endings. So the bash scripts get `\r\n`. I only want to execute them via WSL and I don't want to check the Repo out via WSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is when you do a `git pull` it should automatically convert them to LF (\n) so you can run the files, and then on commit, you want them to be committed at CRLF (\r\n). Here's what you want:

```
git config core.autocrlf false
```

Inside your project `.gitattributes` file:

```
* text eol=crlf
```

Now there are probably only certain file types you want automatically converted. So for example, if they were `.sh` files, you would modify the `.gitattributes` file to:

```
*.sh text eol=crlf
```

Comment: It's not exactly what I wanted, but it pushed me in the right direction. Thanks. 
I keep `autocrlf` but specify `eol=lf` for `*.sh` in the `.gitattributes` file.